# Does placement new operator disable the default new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have a code snippet like this

```
#include <cstring>
#define DISABLE_DEFAULT_NEW                                                    \
  void* operator new(size_t aSize, void* aPtr);                                \
  void operator delete(void* aPtr);

class A
{
public:
  DISABLE_DEFAULT_NEW
  A() {}
};

int
main()
{

  A* a = new A();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I see error messages like this

```
disable_new.cpp:17:10: error: no matching function for call to 'operator new'
  A* a = new A();
         ^
disable_new.cpp:9:3: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  DISABLE_DEFAULT_NEW
  ^
disable_new.cpp:3:9: note: expanded from macro 'DISABLE_DEFAULT_NEW'
  void* operator new(size_t aSize, void* aPtr);                                \
        ^
1 error generated.
```

My question is where does the default new operator go? I'd expect the default syntax of new still work, is it behaviour mentioned anywhere in the spec?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Requiring_or_Prohibiting_Heap-based_Objects does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just *hide* the global ones. If provide [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Class-specific_overloads) at class scope,

(emphasis mine)

> The new expression looks for appropriate allocation function's name firstly in the class scope, and after that in the global scope. Note, that as per [name lookup rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), **any allocation functions declared in class scope hides all global allocation functions** for the new-expressions that attempt to allocate objects of this class.

That means, if you define any `operator new` in the class, you have to define other necessary forms in the class too, e.g.

```
class A
{
public:
  DISABLE_DEFAULT_NEW
  A() {}
  void* operator new  ( std::size_t count ) { return ::operator new(count); } // forward to global operator new
};
```